# Am I getting hacked ? Cloud Firestore huge pick gap of traffic, with no explanation

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, cloudflare

I'm currently facing to a huge pick of Read on Cloud Firestore and no way to go up stream to find the issue. I saw first this increase on Cloudflare. From 1million request to 175millions in 3 days with no correlation with user activity.

[Cloudflare Dashboard before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaPAa.png)
[Cloudflare Dashboard after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yACel.png)

Diving into Statistics from GCP and Firebase is even more confusing had they are reflecting different reality.

[GCP Dashboard Cloud Firestore Read and Write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ0Ed.png)
[Firebase Dashboard Firestore Read and Write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg7Fx.png)

I verified if it was correlated to a new development or new security rule, but nothing.
I was thinking for a time about an hacking but Write seems to follow Read, but sure of nothing.

Can anyone had a previous experience like that, or a hint of where to find more infos on GCP.

Thanks for reading guys

Comment: If you suspect abuse, contact [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) directly.  There's not much Stack Overflow can do for you, since it's for programming questions.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson I'm gonna ticket the service, but from Firebase it doesn't seems to be any issue. I publish here as community might had the same issue before.

Comment: If you're looking for discussion, post to a discussion forum such as Reddit, since this is off-topic for Stack Overflow.